# Is there a way, in Py-Script, to run the input() function?

Tags: javascript, pyscript

When I run the input function inside the pyscript tags like this:

```
<py-script>
    user_input = input("what is your name")
    print(user_input)
</py-script>
```

it will ask the question before the loading screen closes, and the loading screen won't even close until the prompt is answered.

I have tried to use promises in javascript, a text input, and a button to replace the input function in python. However, Py-Script doesn't wait until the promise is resolved and just immediately prints out None. it is almost like py-script is ignoring the wait even though it seems like the promise is still running in the background (i used console.log() to test for that).

And yes, i have already tried to use skulpt and flask and ajax requests. Either they don't work, or they ask the question too early. I just want a way to run python code (with input() functions) in the browser, so if anyone knows any alternatives to py-script, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the js and py-script code btw.

```
<py-script>
from js import input
user_input = input("what is your name?\n") #this input function is the one defined in the js code. not the builtin input function bc that one doesn't work.
</py-script>
```

```
<script>
            var flag = false;
            function click() {
                flag = true;
            }
            function waitUntilTrue() {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                  const check = () => {
                    if (flag == false) {
                      resolve();
                    } else {
                      setTimeout(check, 100); // Wait for 100 milliseconds before checking again
                    }
                  };
              
                  check();
                });
            }
            function input(prompt) {
                $("#show-question").text(prompt); // asks the question.
                waitUntilTrue();
                var userInput = $("#submit-input").val(); //this line gets the text that the user wants to input, or: the answer.
                return userInput;
            }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't use PyScript, but it seems to me that `input()` should translate into the JavaScript `prompt()` function.

Comment: It doesn’t. However, if I do try to translate input into prompt, then the page will freeze on a white screen and will not load until the prompt is answered or cancelled. I am going for a more interactive approach, where pyscript will output a question and then wait until the user answers to continue on with the Python code.

Comment: You're not waiting for the promise in `waitUntilTrue()` to resolve when you call it in `input()`. You need `waitUntilTrue().then(<function that uses the input>)`

Comment: Does PyScript have `async` and `await` like regular Python? You should be using them here, just as you might in JS.